# How to get repeated nearest numbers average in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, logic

##### Input List

```
[0.21,5.0,9.0,0.19,0.2,0.1856,0.9,0.14,0.189]
```

##### Expected output

```
0.19
```

The list above have repeated nearest numbers 0.21,0.2,0.19,0.185,0.189.
Average of 0.21,0.2,0.19,0.185,0.189 = 0.974/5 = 0.1948

**How to extract the repeated nearest numbers in this case?**

> **Note:**- I don't have any approx. assumption on output number or what it can be.

I see counter increment logics like below, that works on List consists int values.But in my case the numbers are not natural numbers.

```py
def most_frequent(List):
  counter = 0
  num = List[0]
    
  for i in List:
    curr_frequency = List.count(i)
    if(curr_frequency> counter):
        counter = curr_frequency
        num = i

  return num
    
List = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
print(most_frequent(List))
```

#### Output

```
2
```

Comment: Do you have a definition of how near is near? Why is 0.21 included but 0.15 is not?

Comment: Because the highest repeated numbers  are around 0.19 cluster. There is no highest repeated numbers around 0.15. If the list consists 0.14,0.155,0.165,0.13 there could be repeated cluster around 0.15, then 0.15 can be output.

Comment: Your definition of "repeated numbers" is unclear.  You seem to mean a clump of close numbers. But how close is close enough to be close.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question lacks to definition of nearest numbers. I would suggest to sort array and calculate diff between all adjacent elements. Then take min difference among them. Let's call it as **min**.

Then in same sorted array try to find consecutive elements set with adjacent elements diff<=**min**. Or give some percentage of flexibility to min by min= min(1+x/100). Where x is percentage of flexibility you want to allow.

Time complexity : O(nlogn).